# Basic physics question concerning the parallelogram law of vector addition (suspected mistake in answer given in textbook)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

### Resolved: Thank you to W H G for the very helpful answer. I couldn't add a comment directly, so I'd like to write it here: your answer was helpful. I now see that I made my calculations in radians as opposed to degrees (the online calculator switched between them regardless of which I clicked on, but I thought it was otherwise). The 73 also threw me off so I didn't consider adding the theta (it would have been 103 --> obviously too large a value). **I now see that the textbook was right, and I had indeed made a silly mistake. Thank you.**

I was going through review questions on basic physics (Schaum's outlines of college physics, 12th edition). I believe that one of the answers to the solved problems is incorrect, and I wanted to ensure that my working of the problem is correct (I also attempted to search for any corrections to this mistake online, but I couldn't find any). This is one of the solved problems of the first chapter (also shown in the attached image):

**Add the following displacement vectors using the parallelogram method: 30 m at 30 degrees and 20 m at 140 degrees**.

**The solution given for the resultant was 30m at 69 degrees (and I suspect that this is a mistake)**.
I tried solving this problem using the Cosine rule, and my working out is as follows:
Diagonal of parallelogram (resultant) = √[(1300 - 2(20)(30)cos(70 degrees)] = 23 m (to two significant figures) (70 degrees because of supplementary angles of parallogram: 180-110 = 70; and the 110 degrees from 140-30)

I then used the cosine rule rearranged for the angle, for which I got a value of 73 degrees (to two significant figures).
Working: cos^-1 [(23^2 + 30^2 - 20^2)/(2 * 23 * 30)]

So **my answer is 23 m at 73 degrees**. Did I make a silly mistake? Or is this correct?
I know this is a very simple physics problem, but my background in physics is quite weak, so I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

I don't have a strong physics background, so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

[image: Image of the problem and solution provided.]

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: Check that this is not physics but [math.se]. I'm voting to migrate it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Comment: I can see that this question is obviously an unnecessary one as it was based on an embarrassing error, so I would happily delete it as it is not of any value. My apologies.

Comment: I tried to delete this question, but was unable to do so. The following notification appeared: 'You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.' I suppose it's not up to me at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would say there is value to using the methods presented in the book just so you know them also.

For the length of the resultant I find you just made an error, I got 29.8 the same as another way that I did it.

In answer to a comment, the angle between the given vectors is 140-30 = 110°. Look at the diagram of the parallelogram to the right of the resultant, the 30m and 20m vectors are 70° apart. For R is the resultant, $R^2= 20^2 + 30^2 -2\cdot 20 \cdot 30 \cos 70$, $R^2=889.6$, $R=29.8 m$.

The original poster apparently worked to get the angle correctly but a wrong length spoiled the answer. I will show some work below.

For the angle between the 30 m and resultant,

$$20^2 = 29.8^2+30^2-2\cdot 29.8 \cdot \cos \theta$$

Therefore, $\theta = 39.1$ and add the 30 degrees (30 m long vector to x axis) to get 69.1 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty bussy right now but you have to consider the sign. Remember that cos(70)=-cos(110) that's why you are getting 23. Apply the same rule at a time to find the resultant angle. Another way is to break down each vector in the X and Y components, that's the hard way tho but you have less margin of error. Let me know if I help you